# Note: “Cloud Firestore Overrides a deprecated API”

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When compiling my Flutter mobile app for Android (seating an APK) I get the following warnings:

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Note: /Users/ez/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /Users/ez/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: /Users/ez/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

There are numerous questions like this on StackOverflow, each one is answered with a different set of plugins versions.

What I did:
1. I've updated my plugins to the latest versions:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # firebase & firestore
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+6
  cloud_functions: ^0.4.0+2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.6
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+7
  # notifications
  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.4
```

2. I've updated android -> build.gradle to:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  // Google Services plugin
    }
```

3. I've updated gradle.properties to:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have to admit I'm not that familiar with all that gradle and dependencies...
Isn't there a proper way to sort all these dependencies out?

Comment: There is no need to add "android.useAndroidX=true" and "android.enableJetifier=true" parts. Just make your minSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 6):

These are not **errors**. These are *notes*, i.e. *deprecation warnings*.
You do not have to worry about it at all. The team developing the Firestore plugin are the only people that need to worry about this and if they think that it is fine for the plugin to use deprecated methods and everything works, there is no problem.

This also means that if your app is not working properly, e.g. not starting, you have a different problem. The logs you posted are completely fine and should not cause any issues.

My conclusion here would be that there is absolutely nothing wrong with what you have posted.

Comment: indeed these are not errors, only warnings.
And the app runs just fine - from what I saw until now.
Still - I'd feel better without these warnings...
Thanks!

Comment: @user6097845 There is nothing you can "do about it" as the plugin uses deprecated methods in the platform implementation. You can just ignore the warnings.

Comment: Well, the app crashes on two of my client's devices.
Tough I can' tell for sure, I suspect it has something to do with these warnings, since this is the first time my app crashes, and it happens whenever it tries to wrote to Firebase DB.
I'd love to know if these warnings indicate on a "problematic" situation that can cause this.

Comment: @user6097845 I thought it became clear from what I wrote before: this has nothing to do with any issue you might encounter. You can *safely* ignore these warnings.

Comment: The crash log (for 3 Android Samsung devices) from Google Play Developer console suggest that it's an issue with Firestore, which is the module in the warnings

Comment: @user6097845 That is possible, however, it does not have anything to do with these "warnings". It might be something else in Firestore. In my answer I tried to explain that these notes can be ignored and do not cause any issues. Therefore, if you are experiencing any issues, they are unrelated to these warnings. Everyone that uses `cloud_firestore` on Android sees these warnings. You might want to investigate your actual issue further and create a new question if you cannot find a solution yourself. (edit: I see that you [already did that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56921961/6509751))

Comment: Any advice on how to further investigate it? Other then checking my code, how can I use this log to pin point the problem? kind of lost here...